# HarshiCorpe Vault: DB credentials collected gets expired, What are the best practices for this case?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I want to understand this case properly from deployment perspective, Suppose DB credentials are retrieved from Vault and they are going to expire. App which is using these credentials is handling financial transactions. Transactions has to be processed without any issue. How to make sure that transactions gets processed even during the updation of DB credentials.

Also, there are side questions like what happens in case where vault updated DB credentials but took a bit of time to update app or vault itself crashed [what I read is that even if one node goes down in Vault, it starts in sealed state] (in which case when it will recover it will again be in sealed state and hence will require a good amount of time) which in my opinion cause sufficiently big production outages.

Need expert opinion on my thoughts and questions

Comment: It really depends on what platform and stack you're running. The advice for nodejs microservices in K8S is completely different from, say, java 10 monolithic apps running in an application server on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to run a side process (also known as sidecar) that renews your secret for as long as the current deployment of your application is running.

For example - your app starts, vault generates secret for the app with expiry of 6 hours. A sidecar process runs and check if the expiry is less than 1 hour, is so - it [renews](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/token/renew.html) the token for 6 hours.

After two days, your application crashes. The sidecar process stops working with it and the token expires.

You can look at [this](https://github.com/WealthWizardsEngineering/kube-vault-auth-renewer) as an example for renewal sidecar.

Comment: Request you to throw some light on last case I described

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject, but you can check out articles about auto unsealing of vaultL https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/enabling-cloud-based-auto-unseal-in-vault-open-source

Comment: I did but didn't find anything much useful to my concerns and hence I raised the questions here